# Running single JUnit Test case inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

I have a set of JUnit test cases.

They successfully run in order when I run maven package.

The issue is when I right click and hit 'Run As JUnit Test Case' in Eclipse I get the following error.

Strangely The m2 folder has the jar file there. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3307)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3293)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2106)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:18)
    at
```

**and the pom.xml is as follows.**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mkl.testarea.pdfbox2</groupId>
    <artifactId>testarea-pdfbox2</artifactId>
    <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
    <name>Test area for public PDFBox v2 issues on stackoverflow etc</name>
    <properties>
        <pdfbox.version>2.0.29</pdfbox.version>
        <bc.version>1.70</bc.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dhorions</groupId>
            <artifactId>boxable</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
            <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.cssbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdf2dom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
        
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-examples</artifactId>
            <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>${bc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>${bc.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <build>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>
          
        </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.11</source>
          <target>1.11</target>
            <testOutputDir>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>   
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the code of a JUnit 4 test or if possible, a JUnit 5 test (by the way, `<plugin><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>...` should not be needed and there is also no Java 1.11 version). Please also show the command line of the JUnit test: in _Run > Run Configurations..._ select the JUnit run configuration and hit the _Show Command Line_ button. Always show the entire stack trace.

Comment: What jar is where? Which one has the missing class?

Comment: don't forget to update PDFBox to 2.0.30.

Answer (score 1):

Running a single Junit test case through IDE capabilities is outside maven and therefore necessary jars should be on the classpath.Adding the jars to the classpath properly did the trick for me.

Comment: Maven dependencies should be added to the classpath or modulepath automatically. Something seems to be wrong with your project settings.